# addClass removeClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My first time asking question here.
I searched through questions but I couldn't find similar problems.

I'm building a corporate website with bootstrap3 on Brackets. I check to see if things work on latest version of chrome and safari.

I'm trying to make my navbar shrink its height and change background color using JQuery addClass and removeClass, but it seems to be not working at all.
When I change CSS property via JQuery, it works. I can change the background color.
So I tried to change multiple CSS properties via Jquery, it wouldn't work. It only allows me to change background color.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $("#top-bar").addClass('animated-header');
    } else {
      $("#top-bar").removeClass('animated-header');
    }
  });

  $("#clients-logo").owlCarousel({
    itemsCustom: false,
    pagination: false,
    items: 5,
    autoplay: true,
  })

}); //this is the part doesn't work

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $("#top-bar").css("background-color", "#ef7c7c");
    } else {
      $("#top-bar").css("background-color", "transparent");
    }
  });

  $("#clients-logo").owlCarousel({
    itemsCustom: false,
    pagination: false,
    items: 5,
    autoplay: true,
  })
}); //this part works perfectly
```

```css
#top-bar {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  padding: 30px 0;
  height: 15%;
}
#top-bar .animated-header {
  /*Background Color of nav bar when scrolled*/
  background-color: #ef7c7c;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 10%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<header id="top-bar" class="navbar-fixed-top animated-header">
  <div class="container">
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have error in your CSS code:

```
#top-bar .animated-header
    /*   ^      
        Here the typo, you specified this properties to
        element, that will be a children of a #tob-bar
        element
    */
```

So, here the right one:

```
#top-bar.animated-header
```

Comment: Thank you!! Is there any way I can check errors in my files with Brackets? I've been writing for like a couple weeks without knowing that was a problem....

Comment: This is not a error, this is just a typo, you just have been confused with selectors.

Comment: But, if you wanna checking errors, you probably wanna to write code in something like Sublime Text or Atom with some plugins, or, if you wanna that editor fully understands your code, you should use IDE (Visual Studio, Intellij Idea, PyCharm)

Answer (score 9):

The problem isn't in the JS using `.addClass()`, the problem is that the selector in your CSS is wrong. This:

```
#top-bar .animated-header {
```

Should be this:

```
#top-bar.animated-header {
```

That is, remove the space before the `.` because *with* the space the selector is matching elements with class `animated-header` that are *descendants* of `#top-bar`. *Without* the space it matches the `#top-bar` element itself if it also has the `animated-header` class.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh my GOSH, thank you so much!! I used a free template to begin with and all of the css descendants are messed up with extra spaces!! I just deleted the spaces b/w #top-bar and .animated-header and it worked!! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Its better to apply all styles in `css`. Change `#top-bar .animated-header` to `#top-bar.animated-header` as you have a extra space here causing your styles not being applied. However if you really wants to apply styles using `jQuery` you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $("#top-bar").addClass('animated-header').css({'background-color': '#ef7c7c', 'height': '10%'});
        } else {
            $("#top-bar").removeClass('animated-header').css({'background-color': '', 'height': ''});
        }
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $("#top-bar").addClass('animated-header');
        } else {
            $("#top-bar").removeClass('animated-header');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
#top-bar {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  padding: 30px 0;
  height: 15%;
}
#top-bar.animated-header {/*Background Color of nav bar when scrolled*/
  background-color: #ef7c7c;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 10%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="top-bar" class="navbar-fixed-top animated-header">
            <div class="container">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I deleted the space and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

> check snippet, a little problem in when you added css it should be 
>   `#top-bar.animated-header` instead of `#top-bar .animated-header`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).scroll(function () {

if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
   $("#top-bar").addClass('animated-header');
   
} 
else {
       $("#top-bar").removeClass('animated-header');  
   
}
});


});
```

```css
#top-bar {
    position:fixed;
 top:0;left:0;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
  padding: 30px 0;
  height: 15%;
}
#top-bar.animated-header {
  /*Background Color of nav bar when scrolled*/

  background-color: #ef7c7c;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 10%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="top-bar" class="navbar-fixed-top animated-header">
  <div class="container">
   logo
    </div></header>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, THAT was the problem!! Now it's working perfectly!

Comment: Happy to help @ReikoKawahara if problem was so then accept this answer as correct one :)